# How do I process iPhone camera data and overlay a 3-D object on it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop an Augmented Reality iPhone application in which I will place a 3D object in front of a live camera feed.

I need to zoom in and zoom out the object as the user moves backward/forward, and rotate the 3D model as the user walks around.

Is there a way to do this on the iPhone ?

Answer (score 1):

The open source [VRToolkit application](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/5-virtual-reality-on-iphone-code-inside) by Benjamin Loulier does just this.  It overlays a 3-D model onscreen in response to coded tags, rotating and scaling them in response to movement of this tag in the area viewed by the iPhone camera.

It leverages the [ARToolkitPlus library](http://studierstube.icg.tu-graz.ac.at/handheld_ar/artoolkitplus.php) to do the marker identification and processing.

However, be aware that this library is GPL-licensed, so you will need to release the source code of any application you build on this under the GPL.

Comment: Can VRToolkit also show for example a basketball on a certain coordinate as a 3d model? I'm looking for something than can this except Layar.

Comment: @Fernando - The VRToolkit sample uses ARToolkitPlus, which processes the image frames from your camera and overlays 3-D objects when it detects certain visual markers.  If you are able to place those markers within your physical location, it could overlay an arbitrary object over them.  Again, note that ARToolkitPlus is GPL-licensed, which means that any application you write using this library must have its source code also released under the GPL.